# How to await for lambada express?

Tags: c#

```
public async Task DownloadFile(string urlAddress, string location)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                
                webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0 Chrome");
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(((sender, e) => await Completed(sender, e, sw)));
                webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler((sender, e) => ProgressChanged(sender, e, sw));

                Uri URL = new Uri(urlAddress);
                
                sw.Start();
                try
                {
                    await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(URL, location);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

getting error on the line :

```
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(((sender, e) => await Completed(sender, e, sw)));
```

on the part :

```
await Completed(sender, e, sw)
```

'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression. Consider marking this lambda expression with the 'async' modifier.

not sure where and how to mark it as async.

Comment: You need to mark the handler lambda async: `async x => { await DoWhatever(); }`

Comment: `(sender, e) =>` -> `async (sender, e) =>`?

Comment: You need to put the async keyword infront of the lambda. e.g. `async (sender, e) => { await Completed(sender, e, sw) }`

Comment: this is working thanks.  async (sender, e) =>